# How to draw/label timelines with gantt

Tags: gantt

[image]I try to create timelines and want to label the timelines/nodes with text, either inside or above/Beneath the timeline. I´ve made extensive investigations but it seems as if I am unable to understand how to do it.

My MWE and the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\scalebox{0.1}{         
\begin{gantt}[xunitlength=0.28cm,fontsize=\large,titlefontsize=\small,drawledgerline=true]{12}{48}               
y unit title=0.7cm,
y unit chart=1.8cm,
time slot format=isodate,
\begin{ganttitle}
\numtitle{1900}{1}{1903}{12}
\end{ganttitle}
\begin{ganttitle}
\newcount\foo
\foo=4
\loop
    \numtitle{1}{1}{12}{1}
    \advance \foo -1
    \ifnum \foo>0
\repeat
\end{ganttitle}    
\ganttbar{21.3 X}{2}{1}
\ganttbar[color=green]{Hamburg}{3}{15}
\ganttbar[color=blue]{L\"uneburg}{13}{20}
\ganttbar{task 1}{2}{17}
\ganttbar[pattern=crosshatch,color=blue]{task 3}{20}{5}
\ganttbar{task 4}{20}{3}\\
\ganttbar[color=green]{task 5}{15}{5}
\ganttbarcon[color=red]{task 6}{20}{5}
\ganttbarcon{task 7}{30}{15}
\ganttbar[color=green]{task 5}{5}{15}
\end{gantt}
}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not able to post the corresponding image because i always get the error message from stackexchange that the "body ist missing" (?)

Comment: Where did you get the `gantt` package from?

Comment: Its part of the LaTeX package on Linux

Comment: It's not on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=gantt) though, which is the main repository for all things TeX, meaning it's not in TeX Live etc. by default. Presumably it's the one found at http://www.martin-kumm.de/wiki/doku.php?id=05Misc:A_LaTeX_package_for_gantt_plots